# Itertools combinations to produce product list

Tags: python, python-itertools

Create combinations of item attributes in order.

Hello, I am trying to create all the combinations of a product in a particular order. The actual problem is quite large, so I have simplified it here but with the same concept. First time using itertools.

Say I am selling a t-shirt. It comes in 3 sizes (s,m,l), 3 colours (w,b,g) and 2 fits (slim,baggy). Put together these make the product code, but have to be in the order of size-colour-fit.

So the combinations are:

S-W-SLIM

S-W-BAGGY

S-B-SLIM

S-B-BAGGY

etc.

My program would need to output all the codes, which should be 3x3x2 = 18 combinations.

```
import itertools

size = ['S','M','L']
colour = ['W','B','G']
fit = ['slim','baggy']


options = itertools.product(size, colour,fit,[3])

print (options)
```

```
<itertools.product object at 0x03718E68>
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

I have had a look at combinations() and permutations() but they only take 2 input arguments?

Unsure where to go from here, TIA.

Comment: Convert it into list `print(list(options))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to a list:

```
print(list(options))
```

Then it will output:

```
[('S', 'W', 'slim'), ('S', 'W', 'baggy'), ('S', 'B', 'slim'), ('S', 'B', 'baggy'), ('S', 'G', 'slim'), ('S', 'G', 'baggy'), ('M', 'W', 'slim'), ('M', 'W', 'baggy'), ('M', 'B', 'slim'), ('M', 'B', 'baggy'), ('M', 'G', 'slim'), ('M', 'G', 'baggy'), ('L', 'W', 'slim'), ('L', 'W', 'baggy'), ('L', 'B', 'slim'), ('L', 'B', 'baggy'), ('L', 'G', 'slim'), ('L', 'G', 'baggy')]
```

Also, you can skip the last argument of `[3]`:

```
options = itertools.product(size, colour, fit)
```

It will output the same, you can check the length and it would be `18`.

If you need dashed between them:

```
options = ['-'.join(i) for i in itertools.product(size, colour, fit)]
```

And the output of:

```
print(options)
```

Would be:

```
['S-W-slim', 'S-W-baggy', 'S-B-slim', 'S-B-baggy', 'S-G-slim', 'S-G-baggy', 'M-W-slim', 'M-W-baggy', 'M-B-slim', 'M-B-baggy', 'M-G-slim', 'M-G-baggy', 'L-W-slim', 'L-W-baggy', 'L-B-slim', 'L-B-baggy', 'L-G-slim', 'L-G-baggy']
```